# PHP download .zip file from another server if the password is correct

Tags: php, ftp, download, zip

I'm working on my very own CMS. I put the latest updates of the CMS into an update folder on the server and the file name is update.zip.

Is there a way for me to call let's say a PHP file on the update server with a variable e.g. http://updateserver.com/update.php?pass=JDFSDH324723HDSFSDJFDSHSD3

And if the pass is correct that then the system may download the .zip file?

Or if you guys can think a better way of making an update system I'm open for suggestions :)

Comment: You can write a script on the "master" server, that will output the contents of the zip file only if called with proper password variable. Extremely simplified: `if ($_GET['pass'] == CORRECT_PASSWORD) {readfile('update.zip');}`

Comment: also "why do you need a password"?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

On the update server:

```
<?php
if ($_GET['pass'] == $thepassword) {
    header('Content-Transfer-Encoding: binary');
    header('Content-Length: '.filesize($zipfile));
    header('Content-Type: application/zip');
    readfile($zipfile);
    exit();
}
else {
    echo 'error';
}
?>
```

Answer (score 1):

I wouldn't suggest using a password here. If you are trying to make a CMS who can update itself, like some CMS, you better use anonymous download and do not check who download it.

If your goal is to make people pay for it, you better register a key on your server side for each client. Then, when they connect to update, they will send the key and if she's in your database and valid, you output your zip file. If not, you don't.

If your CMS is for private use or your company, I think anonymous download would be better since you are not suppose to give the update URL to anyone.

Also, instead of using the function `readfile`, just do a header to the zip location.

Comment: @IlyaKarnaukhov No password at all.

Comment: Ah so I simply tell PHP to download from the PHP and it'll download the zip cause of the headers right?

Comment: Just do `<?php header('Location: zip_location'); ?>` inside your PHP file. So you tell nobody your zip location but people can have access to it.