# How would one secure a PHP script to make it only usable when bought?

Tags: php, security, license-key

I have read [an answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/11229182/1428773) to another question here on Stack Overflow. Let me first quote the incriminated part:

> If your goal is to make people pay for it, you better register a key on your server side for each client. Then, when they connect to update, they will send the key and if she's in your database and valid, you output your zip file. If not, you don't.

I am asking that, technically, how would one secure his/her PHP-based project with the *register a key* method? Let's say we have this:

```
$key = file_get_contents('http://auth.project.example.com/auth.php?auth_key=asd123');
if ( $key === "auth_valid" )
    define('AUTH', TRUE);
```

And after that, we check `AUTH` to see whether we (from the client's perspective) bought the system or not. Obviously, if we did not, `AUTH` will be `FALSE` or would not be defined at all. The problem is, that a client with only *little-to-no* knowledge to PHP would easily comment out these lines, *hotwire* `AUTH` to be TRUE and there he/she is, using the system with it thinking it had been bought, while, in reality, it hadn't.

Comment: ionCube is designed to obfuscate your source and can also allow you to sell it to users on a license-based system.

Comment: Perhaps http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Authentication

Comment: You can move functionality to the server side and only allow API calls from an authenticated user.

Comment: There's no 100% effective way. Even if your code is obfuscated and your application is authenticated with a secret key to your server, there will always be a way of making your script *think* he authenticated with you properly, even though he authenticated right here in my basement. And the best part is, I don't even have to know PHP: I can just install a webserver and use a sniffer or web proxy to analyze requests made to it and have the server respond what your script expects. The best you can do is make it harder to crack.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You would use encryption and eval. Though, thinking about it, once it's evalled, then you have lost, as they could just change eval for echo. So, in that case you'll need to include the business parts on your server via an API.

Answer (score 1):

I would suggest a look at [ZendGuard](http://shop.zend.com/en/zend-guard-annual.html) or [ionCube](http://www.ioncube.com/sa_encoder.php?page=pricing).